# Disable bell systemwide for WSL

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there any way to disable bells at the WSL level? I have to ssh frequently, so simply changing settings in bashrc isn't super helpful... need to be able to do it so that bells are disabled regardless of the remote instance

Comment: turning down the volume by-application might be a practical workaround

Comment: If you ssh to a finite and known number of servers, maybe it is still worth it to just add it to every `.bashrc`